# Javascript function works with onclick but not with onfocus

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have the following javascript function:

```
function makefieldlonger(element) {
    element.style.width = "550px";

}
```

And i call it with a RadTextBox control like this:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"
                                    Skin="Default" Width="255px" onclick="makefieldlonger(this)"/>
```

This works, but i want this to happen in an onfocus event so i do the following:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false"
                                    Skin="Default" Width="255px" onfocus="makefieldlonger(this)"/>
```

But it refuses to adjust its size on the page.
it does call the javascript function (i tested this by putting an alert in the function and it was called).

So the question is: why does this function work with an onclick event but not with an onfocus event?

Comment: what's the value of `this` in your handler, can you change any of the other values ( value or background-color ) ?

Comment: This is in a user control, so i could not find out the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Default" Width="255px" >
    <ClientEvents OnFocus="makefieldlonger" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

OR You can use **`ClientEvents-OnFocus`** property to set the function as @Blade0rz comment

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makefieldlonger(sender, eventArgs)
    {
        sender._element.style.width = "550px";
    }
</script>
```

REF : [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-onfocus.html)

Comment: Or alternative syntax: `<telerik:RadTextBox ClientEvents-OnFocus="makefieldlonger" />`

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly well, i've tried this before but got the object is null error, i dug deeper and i've found out i needed to do the following:

sender._element.width = "550px";

Comment: @NickV Updated answer with your finding, this will help someone else in future. Thanks

Comment: @Damith Sorry i made a typo, it needs to be "sender._element.style.width" Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `OnFocus` takes **two** arguments. I suspect `element` in your function is referring to the event arguments.

Try this (I made it as a `ClientEvent`):

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Default" Width="255px">
    <ClientEvents OnFocus="makefieldlonger" />
</telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Then your function would be:

```
function makefieldlonger(sender, eventArgs) {
    sender.style.width = "550px";
}
```

Taken from the [Telerik RadTextBox Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-onfocus.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using OnBlur() function. You are changing size of textbox on Focus event of that textbox that might cause this error. Use Onblur so that when control leave the Textbox onblur will fire and textbox will get changed